# Rails HABTM setup, model object, & join_table insertion controller setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

I have the following setup.

1 product has many product_types.
many product_types have 1 type.
A HABTM relationship from my understanding of the docs.

My models are

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :types
end

class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

I have a join table migration as such

```
class CreateJoinTableProductTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :products, :types do |t|
      t.index :product_id
      t.index :type_id
    end
  end
end
```

I have created a form - hopefully created correctly where now I have the following parameters being sent on form submit:

```
"product"=>{"name"=>"Product A", "description"=>"A cool product", "image_dir_path"=>"./",
"type"=>{"id"=>"1"}},"commit"=>"Create Product"}
```

I'm wondering 
1) what is the best/rails convention for submitting the parameters for creating the product in the form and controller?

and

2) how are/do I get, the records inserted into the join table?

I have the following method for getting the params

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :image_dir_path, :type,)
end
```

but even then I can see in the logs unpermitted parameter for :type

at the moment my controller only has:

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on the rails way of creating this object. I've read the api docs for HABTM but don't see anything when it comes to the model object or how I should be handling this stuff in the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a `type` in the product. You have many types. You can add `type_ids: [ ]` to  product_params., which is an array of type ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After max's comment I realised Type relationship wasn't a HABTM but was a one to many with product. I had another model Size that was in a HABTM with Product though.

My Models look like this:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sizes
end

class Size < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Join table is:

```
class CreateJoinTableProductSize < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :cakes, :sizes do |t|
      t.index [:product_id, :size_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Size table is default
Product table is

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.references :product_type, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My controller is the default - I just have the following params whitelisted

def cake_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :product_type_id, {:size_ids=>[]})
end

My _form has the following

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :product_type_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:product_type_id, ProductType.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :product_size %>
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:product, :size_ids, Size.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
```

Now I can submit the form, edit it and all values are displayed correctly!

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the only solution that worked for me in rails 5 with habtm udpate and create:
    = f.collection_select(:category_ids, @help_desk.categories, :id, :title)
please note that you have to whitelist the request param for the associated model in this case category_ids

Answer (score 5):

ActieRecord generates `_ids` setters and getters for all [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) associations.

```
# creates 3 rows in products_types if they do not exist
# also deletes any rows not in the array
@product.update(type_ids: [1,2,3])
```

These are used together with the [form options helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models) to assign associations:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :type_ids, Type.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

To whitelist the param you pass it as a option with the value `[]` which permits an array containing any scalar type.

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :image_dir_path, type_ids: [])
end
```

> 2) how are/do I get, the records inserted into the join table?

With the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association you can only insert/access rows indirectly.

For example by:

```
@product.types 
# or
@product.types << Type.first
# or
@product.types.create(name: 'Foo')
```

Or by using the `type_ids` setter/getter previously mentioned. This is a key difference from `has_many through:` where you have a join model that can be queried or created directly.

Comment: Thank you- I'll try this out later on today. Seems to make sense though! :)

Comment: Didn't fully answer my question. I found out that my model Type was really a one to many relationship after I posted this. But I applied the above for another model product and sizes. I tried to stick as much to convention and am finally happy with how its working